# How to convert into Format 2016-10-19T08:00:00Z with momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

in a project we are using momentjs with date. And from backend we become the date in the following format: 2016-10-19T08:00:00Z (don't ask me why...)
Now we are setting a new date in frontend from some selectboxes. And I am trying to convert this in the same format:

```
const date = '25.03.2021'; 
const hour = '13';
const minute = '45'; // this 3 values come from value of selectboxes
const rawDate = moment(date).hour(hour).minute(minute);
// trying to convert to 2021-03-25T13:45:00Z
rawDate.format(); // output: 2021-03-25T13:45:00+00:00
rawDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss'); // output: 03.01.2022 08:00:00
rawDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss z'); // output: 03.01.2022 08:00:00 UTC
rawDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss Z'); // output: 03.01.2022 08:00:00 +00:00
rawDate.toISOString(); // output: 2022-01-03T08:00:00.000Z
```

I know I could probably just use format() or toISOString() and slice/replace the last bit. But I like to know is there a way without any string concat/manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [moment.utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) to ensure your date is in UTC, then use [.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) with the format string `DD-MM-YYYYTHH:mm:ss[Z]`.

I'd also suggest explicity defining the format you are parsing from in the moment() call, e.g. pass 'DD.MM.YYYY' as the second argument.

The reason the backend takes dates in this format is that it's a standardized way of formatting dates to make them machine-readable and consistent ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))

```js
const date = '25.03.2021'; 
const hour = '13';
const minute = '45';

// Raw date will be in the UTC timezone.
const rawDate = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY').hour(hour).minute(minute).utc();

console.log(rawDate.format('DD-MM-YYYYTHH:mm:ss[Z]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I used format('DD-MM-YYYYTHH:mm:ss') + 'Z', the [Z] part is great help, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert to UTC ..?

i.e. Do you intend to make use of a UTC date/time..?

```
const date = '2021-03-25'; 
const hour = '13';
const minute = '45'; // this 3 values come from value of selectboxes
const rawDate = moment(date).hour(hour).minute(minute);
const utc = moment.utc(rawDate);

console.log(rawDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss'));
console.log(utc.format()); //2021-03-25T11:45:00Z
```